# python debugging with vscode SSH

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I want to use the python debugging option in the vcode environment connected to the ssh.
Simple debugging is available, but if I want to put multiple options in args, how can I proceed with debugging?

```
$   python -m src.main -mode train -gpu 0 -embedding roberta -emb_name roberta-base -emb1_size 768 -hidden_size 256 -depth 2 -lr 0.0002 -emb_lr 8e-6 -batch_size 4 -epochs 50 -dataset cv_asdiv-a -full_cv -run_name run_cv_asdiv-a
```